# Accidentally sent Blockchain BCH to Coinbase BTC?

Tags: blockchain, coinbase.com

I have made a mistake by sending cash bitcoin from Blockchain to Coinbase bitcoin address ( instead of Coinbase cash bitcoin address)..

i want to retrieve the fund or send it back to my blockchain so i can input the correct address again ? anyone knows how ? please make it as simple as possible because i do not have a lot of knowledge about bitcoin since i am very new to this world..

I have emailed both Coinbase and Blockchain about this matter, it has been two days and no answer..

thanks for your time and help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly retrieve your fund since they are the one now owning your coins, maybe try to contact their support directly on their social network like twitter to accelerate https://twitter.com/coinbase